In my Next.js 12 project, I've noticed that two stylesheet links are being rendered in the header:
this is links
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/67a61fa87481477c.css" as="style" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/67a61fa87481477c.css" crossorigin="anonymous" data-n-g="">

Having both links causes potential performance issues and redundancy. I want to ensure that only one stylesheet is loaded in my application.
Can someone explain why this happens in Next.js 12?
and how to solve this
Despite my efforts, both the preload and regular stylesheet links are still appearing in the header, leading to potential performance issues and redundancy.
